# map function to ResultIterable in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset like this.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize((('A',('a',1)),('B',('b',3)),('A',('c',3))))
```

What I want to do is:

1. Count how many entries belong to group A/B.
2. Within each group (A/B), count how entries belong to each subgroup (which is 'a','b','c').

As the above example, the answer I want to get is:

- Group 'A': 2

  - subGroup 'a' : 1
  - subGroup 'c' : 1
- Group 'B': 1

  - subGroup 'b' : 1

I can get the first-level result by

```
rdd.countByKey()
```

which returns

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 2, 'B': 1})
```

But how could I get the second-level results?

If I group the data by

```
rdd.groupByKey()
```

How can I map function to the data in each group like map groupByKey again? I notice the value of the results are

```
pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable
```

which can not be applied groupBy or map.

Answer (score 1):

This is a step by step solution.

```
from collections import Counter

rdd = sc.parallelize((('A',('a',1)),('B',('b',3)),('A',('c',3))))
# [('A', ('a', 1)), ('B', ('b', 3)), ('A', ('c', 3))]

a = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list) 
#[('A', [('a', 1), ('c', 3)]), ('B', [('b', 3)])]

b = a.map(lambda line: line[1])
# [[('a', 1), ('c', 3)], [('b', 3)]]

c = b.map(lambda line: [x[0] for x in line])
# [['a', 'c'], ['b']]

d = c.map(lambda line: Counter(line))
# [Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 1}), Counter({'b': 1})]
```

You can use **mapValues(list)** if you want to have a list of the values after the groupByKey() application

If you want to map the information stored in the RDD named as 'd' (in this case `[Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 1}), Counter({'b': 1})]` ) you can see this [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and do:

```
e = d.map(lambda line: list(line.elements()))
# [['a', 'c'], ['b']]
f = d.map(lambda line: list(line.values()))
# [[1, 1], [1]]
```

Comment: Will the last step (Counter) be calculated in a distributed behavior?

Comment: @cssmlulu Why not? As you can see [here](http://takwatanabe.me/pyspark/generated/generated/pyspark.RDD.map.html?highlight=pyspark%20map#pyspark.RDD.map), pyspark.RDD.map will return a new RDD by applying a function to each element of this RDD. You can use the function that you prefer and that function will be applied to every line of your RDD.

Comment: what if I want to do other operations besides count to the subgroups? In the above example, the Counter function do the job for
`subgroup.groupByKey().count()`. What if I do not have the Counter() function?

Comment: I didn't understand if you need this information, that is: when you have `b = a.map(lambda line: line[1]) # [[('a', 1), ('c', 3)], [('b', 3)]]` you have a RDD where every line is your subgroup, so you can do the operations that you need at this level (for example `b_2 = b.map(lambda line: [x[1]*2 for x in line]) # b2 = [[2, 6], [6]]`. Or if you don't want to use Counter for counting elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

`
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(('A', ('a', 1)), ('B',('b',3)),('A',('c',3))))

val grouped = rdd.groupByKey

grouped.map(x => (s"\nTopLevel ${x._1} : ${x._2.size}\nSubLevel ${x._2.groupBy(i=>i.*1).mapValues(*.size)}")).collect
`

[image]

Comment: I change the last line to return only the sub-group size: `grouped.map(x => (x._2.groupBy(i=>i._1)).mapValues(_.size)).collect`

which cause an error. Could you please help me find out the reason?